# react-native-paper code completion for jetBrains ide

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, code-completion, react-native-paper

Intellij uses @types/* libraries for for helping with react code completion.
react-native-paper doesn't have this kind of seperate library.As its author claims it does ship with types inside it:

> https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1492

Well I couldn't get it working how much I tried so I asked it here as the author suggested.What I tried:

1. Added 'allowJS' : true to your jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json file since there was no file like that I created it myself(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/typescript-support.html)
2. The next thing going to Setting->Language And FrameWorks->Javascript->Libraries->Add... click the above plus button attach files and added the directory of the library.

So How do you guys got it working?Please let us know.Thank you so much.

Comment: make sure typescript versions for react-native-paper and IntelliJ are same

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It's not the same but how do I change it?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It doesn't work Please help